# How to compare two dates in yy-dd-mm format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form element of date type:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="InputDOB" id="DOB"
   placeholder="DOB" onblur="dateValidate()" required>
```

The JavaScript code is here:

```
function dateValidate(){
    var date=new Date();
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("DOB");
    alert(pass1.value);
    var date = new Date();

    today=date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth() + 1)+'-'+date.getDate(); 


    if(pass1.value<today){
      alert("date is correct ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `today`, just change your `if` to

```
if(new Date(pass1.value)< date){
 alert("date is correct ");
}

//OR

if(new Date(pass1.value)< new Date()){
 alert("date is correct ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code that you've posted, this is how you do it :

html:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="InputDOB" id="DOB"   placeholder="DOB" required>
```

application.js file that you should load into your HTML file and I'm also using JQuery to accomplish this so you should load it too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DOB").on("blur", function () {
        var date=new Date();
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("DOB");
        alert(pass1.value);
        today=date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth() + 1)+'-'+date.getDate();
        alert(today);


        if(pass1.value<today){
            alert("date is correct ");
        }
    })
});
```

**DEMO:**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/a2fjzqzw/

Answer (score 0):

I always use `moment.js` with JavaScript when messing with dates.  It mitigates most if not all the hardship when manipulating dates in JavaScript and is a brilliant library.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

The difference method may get you where you need, if not I'm sure you can find a solution in the API.

Comment: I didn't recommand to use moment.js for just a compariason, see the response of Sourabh with the use of Date()

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `getTime();` to compare two dates like

```
function dateValidate(){
    var input = document.getElementById("DOB");
    alert(input.value);
    var inputDate = new Date(input.value).getTime();
    var today = new Date().getTime();
    if(inputDate<today){
      alert("date is correct");
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwbdau8L/)**